# How to group the headers and add where condition inside the select statement

Tags: c#, linq

Please refer below data table Image

[image]

Header contains two sets of values

1. Difficult to use/Understand
2. Delivery Issues

I want to group the header and get the category percentage  like below code

```
 var p = from linq_row in trend_data.AsEnumerable()
                    group linq_row by linq_row["Header"] into g
                    select new
                    {

                        categorypercentage = g.Select(s => s["categoryPercentage"].ToString()).ToArray()
                    };
```

above linq will group the header and return the categorypercentage same for the headers

but what i want is i need two sets of variable instead of one single variable

```
var p= from.....
      select new
       {
       firstgroupedheadercategorypercentage= g.select ....and some where clasue
       secondgroupedheadercategorypercentage= g.select ....and some where clasue
}
```

how can i do or perform the operation of inserting where clause in inside of select new statement.

i need to get category percentage based upon the header value.

Comment: Why do you want to group by the header at all if the desired result is only a single anonymous type that contains two properties? I don't understand why you want an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` then.

Comment: @Tim if you want particular categorypercentage for particular header means that time i will iterate all through loop and will do some if condition. instead of that if two variables holding the value means that is easy to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the sum of the percentage column of every group:

```
var headerPercentages = trend_data.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Header"))
    .Select(g => new { Header = g.Key, Percentage = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("categoryPercentage"))});
```

If you want a single anonymous type instance as result with two poperties for these specific headers:

```
var x = new {
    firstHeaderPercentage = trend_data.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Header") == "Difficult to use/Understand")
        .Sum(r => r.Field<double>("categoryPercentage")),
    secondHeaderPercentage = trend_data.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Header") == "Delivery Issues")
        .Sum(r => r.Field<double>("categoryPercentage"))
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually i am not expecting sum of percentages. just i need to get array of category percentage only

Comment: @SivaRajini: then use `Select`+`ToArray` instead of `Sum`.

Comment: You are awesome. you taught me some logic in linq. if possible could you please post basic linq tutorials here to learn

Comment: @SivaRajini: thanks a bunch. SO is not the place to post tutorials. I've learned a lot here by trying to help others or learning from better answers.